# Next switch in ListView get also checked when checked the previous one

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a Todo project in Android using a ListView. Each item of my listview have one switch in order to delete the task, one TextView and one ImageView. The problem is when I check a switch of a specific task, the task is deleted (desired behavior) but it checks the following one too (without deleting it) .

Here is the code of my Adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<Tache> lesTaches;
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public Adapter(Context context, List<Tache> list) {
    this.context = context;
    lesTaches = list;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return lesTaches.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return lesTaches.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;

    if(convertView == null) {
        view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tache_item, parent, false);
    } else {
        view = (View) convertView;
    }

    TextView intitule = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.intitule);
    intitule.setText(lesTaches.get(position).getIntitule());

    final Switch switch1 = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(buttonView.isPressed()) {
                if(isChecked) {
                    remove(lesTaches.get(position));
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}

public void remove(Tache toDel) {
    lesTaches.remove(toDel);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addItem(Tache toAdd) {
    lesTaches.add(toAdd);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}}
```

And here is my tache_item.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
    android:focusable="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/intitule"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/switch1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon_info"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_info_black" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is a screen of my app showing the problem (I deleted the first task so we do not see it but the second one get checked):
Image showing the problem:
[image: Image showing the problem]

I already search on the net and test to replace the setOnCheckedChangeListener by an onClickListener but the same problem appear.

Comment: I've not clear what you're trying to obtain, could you explain in step?

Comment: Ok sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Ok @GianlucaBenucci sorry if I wasnt clear, so the purpose is to delete a task when i click on the task's switch. But the problem is at the moment when I click on a switch it delete the task but it checked the following one too.

Comment: At first view maybe the buttonView.isPressed() is wrong. Try buttonView.isChecked()

Comment: Thanks for your reply @GianlucaBenucci but unfortunately same result, the task is deleted and the second one get checked with no reason.

Comment: Could you add the R.layout.tache_item xml?

Comment: Sure, it is done @GianlucaBenucci

Comment: I can't understand how to solve the problem, any idea @GianlucaBenucci?